# How to detect when user tap on Shift key and Shift mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard

I can use `UITextViewDelegate` or `NSNotificationCenter` to detect when user tap character key on `Keyboard` to input text to `UITextView`.

But my App need to detect when user tap on `Shift key` and I also want to detect which `Shift mode is activated`. It's mean I want to detect when user gonna to type in lower case, Upper first character or Upper all characters mode.

I search so much but can't find good solution. Please help!

Comment: You can't, at least not easily. You can't even intercept the touch events themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to implant your own custom keyboard (which may require a custom text view as well), as there currently appears to be no public API exposing this information on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do a regular expression check for keys of A to Z ?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // check if string entered matches regular expression [A-Z]
    if(matchedRegularExpression)
    {
        NSLog(@"uppercase character detected");
    }    
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"lowercase character detected");
    }

    return true;
}
```